# Constructor is being invoked twice

Tags: c++

In code:

```
//file main.cpp
LINT a = "12";
LINT b = 3;
a = "3";//WHY THIS LINE INVOKES CTOR?


std::string t = "1";
//LINT a = t;//Err NO SUITABLE CONV FROM STRING TO LINT. Shouldn't ctor do it?

//file LINT.h
#pragma once
#include "LINT_rep.h"
class LINT
{
private:
    typedef LINT_rep value_type;
    const value_type* my_data_;
    template<class T>
    void init_(const T&);
public:
    LINT(const char* = 0);
    LINT(const std::string&);
    LINT(const LINT&);
    LINT(const long_long&);
    LINT& operator=(const LINT&);
    virtual ~LINT(void);

    LINT operator+()const;               //DONE
    LINT operator+(const LINT&)const;//DONE
    LINT operator-()const;               //DONE
    LINT operator-(const LINT&)const;//DONE
    LINT operator*(const LINT&)const;//DONE
    LINT operator/(const LINT&)const;///WAITS FOR APPROVAL

    LINT& operator+=(const LINT&);//DONE
    LINT& operator-=(const LINT&);//DONE
    LINT& operator*=(const LINT&);//DONE
    LINT operator/=(const LINT&);///WAITS FOR APPROVAL
};
```

in line number 3 instead of assignment optor ctor is invoked. Why? I'm willing to uppload entire solution on some server otherwise it's hard to put everything in here. I can also upload video file. Another thing is that when I implement this assignment optor I'm getting an error that this optor is already in obj file? What's going on?

Comment: Could you post your the implementation of the "="-operator?

Comment: What is `LINT`? Why `LINT a = "12"` before `#pragma once` and `#include`? It is impossible to change a variable out of any function.

Comment: @Alexey Malistov I'm sorry my fault I should mention this code is from two different files. Going to fix it;

Comment: I can't help but your avatar pic in the iconized version looks fun :)

Comment: I suggest you read up on `explicit` to prevent these types of conversions when you don't want them.

Comment: Ok, you know your problem better than I do. In my experience however, I almost always make constructors explicit. I think Stroustrup has even said it should have been the default, and you'd have to ask for the implicit conversion behavior instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have an `=` operator which takes a RHS of `std::string` (or `char*`), so, the literal '3' is being constructed to a `LINT`, and then assigned using your `=` operator.

EDIT: As for the 2nd question in your code, you need to call `c_str()` on the `std::string` to get the `char*` buffer of the string, then the same thing will happen as with your literal 3.

Answer (score 6):

Your assignment operator takes a LINT object as a  parameter, but when you say:

```
a = "3";
```

you are handing the assignment op a string literal, not a LINT object. The compiler needs to create a LINT object that the assignment op can use, so it calls the constructor that takes a `const char *` as a parameter to do that.

Comment: @Neil Shall I understand that your answer to my question means that we are cool from now or you've just made a mistake and didn't realize whos question is it?

Answer (score 4):

The following constructor:

LINT(const char* = 0);

will be called for literal assignment "3" because it is acting as an implicit constructor call.  If you wish to avoid that, prefix the constructor with the 'explicit' qualifier.

Also add an assignment operator for any types you wish to assign without implicit construction.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no assignment operator specified which could be used. You probably need something like: 
`LINT& operator=(const char*);`

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you:  Wrong.  The compiler will only generate a copy assignment operator (that is, one whose RHS is the same type as the class itself (modulo const&).  Conversion assignment operators are never generated by the compiler.

Comment: @Drew Hall  I seat corrected. You are absolutely right. I was wrong. Didn't take into account that there is conversion being applied.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor

```
LINT(const char* = 0);
```

acts as **conversion constructor** for assignments to `char*` (e.g. `LINT a = "3"`). Your `=()`-operator only is called if you assign a LINT object to another LINT object.

```
LINT a;
LINT& b = a
LINT& c = LINT("4");
```

The expressions above will call your `=()`-operator.

Answer (score 1):

There is `LINT& operator=(const LINT&);` 
There is no `LINT& operator=(const char *);` 
But there are many implicit ctors.
Therefore implict ctor is invoked.

Comment: And what about not being able to convert string to LINT?

Comment: And why I'm getting an err when I try to implement operator=()?

Comment: @All AFTER spending some time I decided to go easy and I've just created new Solution, I've copied those files (*.h & *.cpp) and surprise surprise no more problems with not being able to convert string to LINT and no more problem with operator=().

Answer (score 0):

The only assignment operator your LINT class defines is the copy assignment operator, `LINT& operator=(const LINT&)`.  Thus, on line 3, when you attempt to assign a static C-style string (const char[]) to a LINT object, the compiler recognizes that there is no matching assignment operator.

However, the compiler is allowed to use one user-defined type conversion to make the call work.  It selects the LINT(const char*) constructor to turn the const char[] into a LINT object, then invokes the copy assignment operator on the temporary LINT object it creates for the right-hand side.

You can avoid this temporary by providing a `LINT& operator=(const char*)` assignment operator to augment your copy assignment operator.